# How can I get a HTML code that display time?

Tags: html, datetime

I need a html code that display current time (12 hrs) and after some seconds it show name of the day (Saturday, Sunday) after some seconds it show date and then show time and so on with loop. can anybody help me?? thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please edit your question so that it attempts to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is just blatantly asking someone to magically code it for you.

Comment: HTML code doesn't do that. You need a programming language

Answer (score 1):

You need to write some Javascript to actually do it for you:

```js
let dt = new Date;
console.log(dt)
```

You can also use the methods `Date` has:

```js
let dt = new Date;
console.log("Year: ", dt.getFullYear())
console.log("Month: ", dt.getMonth())
// Or to get the name of the month:
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
console.log("Month name: ", monthNames[dt.getMonth()])
//Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/135589/jesper!
console.log("Day: ", dt.getDay()) //Returns day of the week!
//etc...
```

More reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date